# Are Gutenberg books illegal to sell in Germany or any non-US countries?

Tags: copyright, international, public-domain, publishing

I am building an eBook reading service (paid) and I aim to distribute free classics available on Gutenberg Project. (at least for the start)

I have gone through [all Gutenberg terms](https://www.gutenberg.org/policy/permission.html) which allows me to do almost anything, but Gutenberg being limited to the US, it doesn't say much beyond that.

I just came to know that Gutenberg is banned in Germany, because of a [lawsuit arising out of the situation](https://cand.pglaf.org/germany/index.html) that copyright expiry differs between Germany and the US (where Gutenberg is located).

**My questions are:**

Does this mean I cannot sell any books in Germany? Are there exceptions? (By selling I do not mean to sell one book for €xx - it is rather unlimited books per month sort of, but it is no different from selling)

- Is there a central place to know how many years old books could be safe to publish, in every country?
- Is there another thing that I am completely overlooking (beyond number of years passed since published / author died)?
- If there is a safer, more copyright-free + generic source than Gutenberg to find such books?
- If at all infringement occurs, what sort of difficulties could arise for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not correct to say that "Gutenberg is banned in Germany". A German court ruled that Project Gutenberg (US) could not provide copies of 18 works to addresses in Germany. PGLF (the foundation that runs Project Gutenberg) decided to block all access from Germany, because similar claims might be made about other works, leading to added legal expense in Germany.  PGLF is said to be appealing the German Court's decision.

Many works in the PG collection are clearly out of copyright in Germany, under German law. Providing those works would not infringe German copyright.  As long as the PG license is complied with (and it is quite permissive) I see no legal problem with such works, but anyone planning to start a business or service reproducing such works would be wise to consult a lawyer with knowledge of copyright law in that person's country.

Note that there are PG affiliates in several countries, including Germany and Australia, that operate under their own local copyright rules, and are run separately, and have different collections of works.

Comment: it's a little more complicated: OLG Frankfurt (aM) did affirm the LG Frankfurt (aM) ruling [here](https://www.lareda.hessenrecht.hessen.de/bshe/document/LARE190035180). PArt of the first ruling was, that PG had to disclose who did download it, but the German publisher said, that what they discovered since then would suffice their requests. PG asked for special permission to appeal in front of the BGH, which is still pending. Meanwhile, for similar reasons, in June 2020, [Italy ordered PG Blocked](https://assets.documentcloud.org/documents/6934022/0053965-2020.pdf)

Comment: Link to where the resulting case shall appear (German): https://dejure.org/dienste/vernetzung/rechtsprechung?Gericht=BGH&Datum=31.12.2222&Aktenzeichen=I%20ZR%2097/19

Comment: @Nirav Bhatt My understanding is that if you retain the PG header, you must offer under the PG license, which means permitting others to reuse. If the PG hjeader is removed, you may use any license at all, but must not mention PG or use its trademarks. I was for a whjile a regular volunteer for PG, digitizing works.

Comment: @DavidSiegel sorry I accidentally deleted my comment, but I meant to ask two things, one of which you already answered. [Many works](http://gutenberg.org/files/11/11-0.txt) is still under some gray area, and despite being popular (precisely because of it), I seem to be unable to use it.

Comment: "If you are not located in the United States, you'll have
to check the laws of the country where you are located before using this ebook." <== found in almost all books on Page 1..[popularity descending](http://gutenberg.org/ebooks/search/?sort_order=downloads)...Maybe they are being defensive after Germany issue...

Comment: @Nirav Bhatt  any reuser is responsible for checkign teh local copyright status of amny work s/he plans to reuse. In most cases this should be easy. works where one cannot be sure can simply be lefdt out of any reuse. I don't understand what you mean by "I seem to be unable to use it" What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Nirav Bhatt  "If you are not located in the United States, you'll have to check the laws of the country where you are located before using this ebook." has been part of teh PG legalese for at least two decades, long before this german suit, vwcause they knew that copyright laws differed in different countries. If you want to publish PG-derived works in country X, it is your responsibility to check the laws of X, and avoid works still in copyright in X.

Comment: @DavidSiegel interesting. But it is not entirely true. I saw this text [not in every piece](http://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/174/pg174.txt), which makes my work easier for those cases. But usually popular books has that phrase....like I showed in [Alice's case](http://gutenberg.org/files/11/11-0.txt).

Comment: @DavidSiegel so I would have wished to have search filter that gives me separate results for Alice in Wonderland (check in your country) vs Picture of Dorian Gray (no need to check)

Comment: @DavidSiegel off course I do not mean any disrespect or entitlement, Gutenberg is a great job - just explaining my usage of words describing my problem.

Comment: @Nirav Bhatt  That sentence does not mean the work  may not be used, jsut that you must check. I think that *Alice* is free of copyright everywhere in the world, for example. If that text is absent, you still must check. I don't know why it is absent from some ebooks -- perhaps an older form of the header did not use the text. But one still must check.

Comment: @DavidSiegel ah ok. That settles it, then. As someone who has volunteered for the work, I accept that as source of truth. Thanks for the support all along, and great work.